# How to connect Mongo DB using Compass running as a container in Windows 10 env?

Tags: mongodb, docker

My docker is running in windows 10 env with IP address: 192.168.##.###

I started my mongodb as a container using command:

```
docker container run -p 28000:27017 --name mongodb --detach mongo:3.4
```

I successfully connected from docker env to mongo db using mongodb shell as follows:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo
```

I could not connect to mongodb instance using my windows IP address and port number 28000 from MongoDB compass.

How can I  connect?

Answer (score 0):

I executed following commands and found the IP address of my docker machine:

```
$docker-machine ls
```

NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.12.0-ce

```
$ docker-machine env
```

export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"

export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"

Then by passing the IP Address 192.168.99.100 and Port number 28000, I successfully connected to my Mongodb instance running in container.